# How to access react contexts and/or hooks in redux actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Could someone please tell me if it is a good idea to access contexts and/or hooks in redux actions or would it be better to always pass them as arguments from components.

Currently the only way I have managed to do this is by creating a custom dispatch hook:

```
function useDispatchWithHooks () {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const hooks = {...useContext(AlertContext), ...useContext(WindowContext), ...useTranslation(), etc... };

    return (action) => {
        if (typeof action === 'function') {
            return action({ ...hooks }, dispatch);
        }

        return dispatch(action);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
   const dispatch = useDispatchWithHooks();

    dispatch (({showAlert, translate}, dispatch) => {
        showAlert(translate('alert'), translate('createdTab'));
        dispatch( { type: INITIALIZE_TAB });
    });
```

Comment: Hello Lance. Why do you need to use both redux and context ? Usually you would use one or the other or Mobx

Comment: i find context works better than redux for some things like modals and global states like window size but it causes some problems when used for all of the apps state. Also this useTranslation is a hook, which I should have stated in the question, will update it now..